# Touchpad delayed on Dell Precision 5520

Tags: mouse, touchpad, dell

I bought a Dell Precision 5520 with Ubuntu pre-installed. For the first year, everything seemed to work fine. Then after a recent package update, my touchpad started to act weird. One day it completely stopped working. After a reboot, it seemed to work fine again. Then after I did a suspend/resume, now it delays for about 2 seconds when I try to use it, which resets after I lift my finger off. As you can imagine, this essentially makes the touchpad unusable.

I've seen some [similar reports](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/3x2ny0/xps_1315_trackpad_delay_solution/) on other sites, but they all involve using some Windows program to tweak mouse/touchpad settings, which isn't an option under Linux.

I found [this solution](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lang=en), but it's only for when `xinput list` shows two touchpads, whereas my output doesn't.

How do I fix the "touchpad lag" problem on Linux?

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem? I have a similar issue on a Dell Latitue 7490.